# Error while importing project : Manifest merger failed

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-manifest

I have imported a project but it's not working. I have looked other questions related to Manifest merger failed, but is not solving my problem.
This is the error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1] F:\Softwares\Project\Bird\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\10.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage.

And this is my gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

This is my Android manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="bb.bird"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that somewhere in your app a Manifest contains a minimum sdk version 1.
You should control this by adding

```
minSdkVersion 9
```

in your app's build.gradle file under the block

```
defaultConfig
```

This should be enough, otherwise you can check all the manifests and gradle files and look where the minSdkVersion 1 is defined.